# Is there a limit to the number of USB and Serial to USB devices my Macbook Pro can connect?

Tags: usb

I'm curious if there is a limit to the number of usb and serial to usb devices my Mac can connect to. I've got a 2015 Macbook Pro running 10.10.5 and I'm writing a python program to connect to a bunch of serial devices which I have connected to a USB hub. I have four devices on one hub and then two on another. My computer seems to have some weird issues when I connect to all of them and chat with them over serial. Any idea about limits here?

Comment: The answer is probably "No", but depending on the characteristics of the weird issues you see it might be timing issues or similar which would require some programming changes. Developer questions are off-topic on AD though, they can be asked on Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice! Turns out I just wasn't closing my serial connections so they we leading to some unexpected behavior and dragging the program down. Closing the open connections fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you connect too many devices through USB hubs, but, as @patrix mentioned, you might experience slower data transfer rates and delays.